# Bash Shell file convert .sass ans .scss into css

Tags: bash, shell, sass

I'm trying to build a sass workspace.

**I - Goal**

I have two directories :

- One is a SASS directory that contain .sass or .scss files,
- One is a CSS directory that contain .css files.

/css is a destination directory for /sass files convertion result.

My goal is to code sass or scss in /sass directory, and call a bash file to convert each .sass or .scss file from /sass into a .css result in /css directory.

**II - What I did:**

[/!\ Maybe useless to read it entirelly, firstly go to the part III which explain the problem.]

Here is my /convert bash file :

```
SASS_FILES_PATH=sass
CSS_DEST_PATH=css

function get_cleaned_filename {
        # Split fileName to removre file directory:
        IFS='/' # Split delimiter
        read -ra ADDR <<< "$1"
        local ARRAY_LENGTH=${#ADDR[@]}
        RESULT="${ADDR[$ARRAY_LENGTH - 1]}"

        # Split fileName to removre file type:
        IFS='.' # Split delimiter
        read -ra ADDR <<< "$RESULT"
        RESULT="${ADDR[0]}"
}

# function convert_file/1 convert the file in parameter into .css file
# Parameters : $1 : path to source file
# Precondition : file in parameter should have .scss ou .sass extension
#               
# Postcondition : create a .css and a .css.map files that correspond to
#   the converted .sass or .scss file.
function convert_file {
        get_cleaned_filename $f;
        FILENAME=$RESULT;

        #   We can have two files .sass and .scss using the same name :
        if test -f $CSS_DEST_PATH/$FILENAME.css;
        then
            echo "a file $CSS_DEST_PATH/$FILENAME.css exist";
            FILENAME=$FILENAME_2;
            echo "renamed to $FILENAME_2";
        fi
        
        echo "[DEBUG]: sass ${f} ${CSS_DEST_PATH}/${FILENAME}.css";
        sass --trace ${f} ${CSS_DEST_PATH}/${FILENAME}.css;
}

if ! test -f $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.sass || ! test -f $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.scss;
then
    echo "Pas de fichier à convertir dans le dossier, aucune opération n'a été éxécutée.";
else 
    #   Empty CSS_DEST_PATH :
    if test -f $CSS_DEST_PATH/*;
    then 
        for cssFileName in $CSS_DEST_PATH/*;
        do
            rm $cssFileName;
        done
    fi

    #   Convert every .scss and .sass files into .css

    #   If scss file exist in curent directory
    if test -f $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.scss;
    then
        #   Convert each .scss file into css and move it to css directory
        for f in $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.scss;
        do 
            convert_file $f;
        done
    fi

    #   If sass file exist in curent directory
    if test -f $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.sass;
    then
        #   Convert each .sass file into css and move it to css directory
        for f in $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.sass;
        do 
            convert_file $f;
        done
    fi
fi
```

**III - What is the mistake:**

In function convert_file\1, i have a mistake :

```
        echo "[DEBUG]: sass ${f} ${CSS_DEST_PATH}/${FILENAME}.css";
        sass --trace ${f} ${CSS_DEST_PATH}/${FILENAME}.css;
```

The sass call (second line) return an error:

```
me@myComputer:~/Desktop/computing/sassWorkshop$ bash convert
[DEBUG]: sass sass/test.scss css/test.css
Traceback (most recent call last):
    7: from /usr/bin/sass:8:in `<main>'
    6: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
    5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
    4: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:52:in `process_result'
    3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:120:in `process_result'
    2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:182:in `open_file'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:182:in `open'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/exec/base.rb:182:in `initialize': No such file or directory @rb_sysopen - sass/test (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Note that "convert" is the name of the bash file i use !

The thing i don't understand is that my echo "[DEBUG]: ..." line print that according to my variables, the sass call is "sass sass/test.scss css/test.css". But when i type this line into my terminal, the line works well and my .css file is created.

**IV - What i tried:**

I tried "rm .sass-cache/ -R" which don't changed anything.

I'm sorry if my post isn't well formed, or if there is many English mistakes (not my mother thong) if it's the case told me please :)

Thanks for any comment than can help me

Comment: Tangentially, don't use upper case for your private variables; all-uppercase names are reserved for system variables.

Comment: @HedwinBonnavaoud : Could it be that some of the files in your `sass` directory have names with embedded white space?

Comment: Thanks for this hint @tripleee, i will take care about that.

Comment: no @user1934428 I no white spaces, every file names are like something_somthingelse.sass whout caps and without others characters than '_'.

Comment: In this case, the only thing we know is that Ruby tries to open `sass/test`, which we know doesn't exist, and it must get this name from somewhere, most likely from the command arguments. Did you try to run it under `-x` to see, what's actually going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really check your script with shellcheck.net as it contains several errors, mainly due to missing double quotes around variables, use of deprecated test and something that I can't explain:

`FILENAME=$FILENAME_2;`

The value of the variable `FILENAME_2` is not set.

Also:
`if ! test -f $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.sass || ! test -f $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.scss;`

`-f` does not work with globs, so you need to iterate each globbing to update flags and test each flag, or better use the `find` command return code

`if ! find "$SASS_FILES_PATH/" -name '*.sass' || ! find "$SASS_FILES_PATH/" -name '*.scss'`

Useless and dangerous unsecured `rm` loop:

```sh
        for cssFileName in $CSS_DEST_PATH/*;
        do
            rm $cssFileName;
        done
```

Replace with

```sh
        rm -- "$CSS_DEST_PATH/"*
```

Same issue, cannot test `-f` with globbing:

```sh
    #   If scss file exist in curent directory
    if test -f $SASS_FILES_PATH/*.scss;
```

This will test files exist and execute the conversion on each entry:

```sh
    find "$SASS_FILES_PATH" -name '*.scss" -o -name '*.sass' -exec convert {} \;
```

Your function to clean file-name is suboptimal:

```sh
function get_cleaned_filename {
        # Split fileName to removre file directory:
        IFS='/' # Split delimiter
        read -ra ADDR <<< "$1"
        local ARRAY_LENGTH=${#ADDR[@]}
        RESULT="${ADDR[$ARRAY_LENGTH - 1]}"

        # Split fileName to removre file type:
        IFS='.' # Split delimiter
        read -ra ADDR <<< "$RESULT"
        RESULT="${ADDR[0]}"
}
```

Instead:

```sh
function get_cleaned_filename {
        filename="${1##*/}"    # remove leading directories path
        echo "${filename%\.*}" # remove dot suffix
}
```

Then in `convert_file`:

```sh
function convert_file {
        FILENAME="$(get_cleaned_filename "$1")";
```

Finally, this may do what you want:

```sh
find sass/ -type f \( -name '*.scss' -o -name '*.sass' \) -exec bash -c 'src="$0"; _tdest="/${0%\.*}"; dest="css/${_tdest##*/}.css"; rm -f "$dest"; sass --trace "$src" "$dest"' {} \;
```

or

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find sass/ -type f \( -name '*.scss' -o -name '*.sass' \) -exec bash -c '
  # Source file (.scss or .sass) passed as argument 0
  src="$0" 

  # Strip-out file name extension
  _tdest="/${0%\.*}"

  # Construct destination file path/name.css
  dest="css/${_tdest##*/}.css" # Construct destination file path/name.css

  # Remove destination file if it exists
  rm -f "$dest"

  # Perform the scss|sass compilation
  sass --trace "$src" "$dest"
' {} \;
```

Comment: Ok all these hints are really usefull i will check that, 

But about "FILENAME=$FILENAME_2;", I mean "add '_2' at the end of $FILENAME" but maybe something like "FILENAME=`${FILENAME}_2" is better ?

Comment: Yeah, the braces are required to keep the underscore out.